# Is there any lock mechanism in ruby's C extension for thread safety?

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

Anything like python's Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS and Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS?

Comment: Do you mean you want to engage the Global Interpreter Lock?

Comment: yes~I hope there is a high level macro. But I would like to see any possible solution.